# ¿Qué restricción poner para poder restar la fecha actual menos la de inicio (experiencia) en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando una base de datos que almacena información sobre tiendas de aplicaciones móviles y tengo una tabla de una relación N:N (trabajan) que se crea entre las entidades empleados y empresas.

Dentro de la tabla de la relación `trabajan`, tengo el atributo `Fecha_inicio` y `Fecha_fin` que son de tipo **DATE** y estos atributos los tengo para que me calcule la experiencia que llevan en sus respectivas empresas, es decir, *la resta de* `fecha_fin` y `fecha_inicio`.

Entonces, hay empleados que ya están despedidos, pero hay otros que continúan en la empresa, entonces tenía pensado poner esos valores en `NULL` (es decir, dejarlos vacíos sin meter datos en `Fecha_fin` de esas filas determinadas). Y en el código donde hago el `CREATE TABLE`, poner una restricción del tipo `CHECK IF (Fecha_fin) IS NULL = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, para decirle que si el registro en esa columna está vacío, que ponga la fecha actual del sistema.

Pero esa sintaxis está mal formulada y no sé como arreglarlo.

Os dejo por aquí parte del codigo:

```
CREATE TABLE TRABAJAN (
codEmpleado SMALLINT,
codEmpresa SMALLINT,
Fecha_inicio DATE,
Fecha_fin DATE,
CHECK (IF (Fecha_fin) IS NULL = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -- Esto es lo que quiero cambiar
PRIMARY KEY (codEmpleado, codEmpresa),
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpleado) REFERENCES Empleados(codEmpleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpresa) REFERENCES Empresas(codEmpresa)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

En conclusión, me gustaría arreglar esa línea o aprender a hacerlo de otra forma más óptima.

Y por último, ¿La resta entre esos dos atributos de fecha la tendría que hacer en una consulta posteriormente, no?

Comment: No sería más fácil añadir una campo "activo" que represente si está trabajando actualmente? Que ocurriría si vuelves a contratar al mismo trabajador unos meses de dejar de trabajar ahí? Si pones nulls en esos campos pierdes esa referencia de los periodos de trabajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta

```
Fecha_fin DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Todo registro que ingrese en NULL, tendrá la fecha actual del servidor.
Revisa la documentación sobre los DEFAULT, tendrás que usarlos bastante.

Otra cosa es que es mejor que los campos tipo DATE nunca sean NULL, SQL por defecto no lo permite, en cambio para valores indefinidos puedes usar fechas imposibles como 0000-00-00